# OSGi retrieving the BundleContext from an applet

Tags: java, applet, osgi

I've made an osgi Bundle that register an html page with an embedded applet.

The plug in project is structured as follow:

```
/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
/thesis/bot/wab/Activator.class      //BundleActivator
/thesis/bot/wab/Applet/DApplet.class //extends JApplet
/home.html
```

How can i get the BundleContext from DApplet?

Comment: How do you use OSGi with applet? Launch or embed (see this article http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html) ?

Comment: I'm using equinox embedded in Tomcat (using the servlet bridge),for use the applet i've registered an html page with the Applet tag using httpservice and i've registered also the .class files that the applet need. It works but i don't know how to get bundlecontext.

Comment: Just because OSGi is running inside Tomcat doesn't mean it's also running inside the applet. The applet is running in the web browser on a different computer -- it's a completely different environment.

Comment: @NeilBartlett Yes i know, so i'm changing the applet to use TCPsocket for communicate with a Bundle that retrieve the informations and send back it to the Applet. I've written the question to ask if there is an alternative way.

Comment: Applet lives in another environment altogether (the browser), and osgi context lives on server side. You'll probably want an interface in between, like an HTTP-based interface.

Comment: @DuccioB. So the question now is, why on earth would you want to get the BundleContext for the server-side code from an applet running in the browser?? What could you possibly use this for? Have you accounted for the fact that the applet could be running many instances concurrently on many browsers? And besides... who on earth still uses applets in 2013???

Comment: @NeilBartlett this is for a universitary project.I am making a simulation of a swarm of robot implemented with OSGi (every robot's module is an OSGi Bundle that exposes a service) and i should "hot deploying" elements in the virtual environment through the browser. After this i should display (in the browser) the activities of this "robots" and provide an interface for deploying the new elemnts.

Comment: @DuccioB. The requirements still don't make any sense to me. An OSGi BundleContext is intended to be used within the local OSGi framework, you shouldn't try to access it from a remote computer. Maybe you're looking for something like Remote Services instead.

Comment: So the answer is: there is no way. I've tried to use socket and to serialize the objects needed and it seems to work, so i'ill proceed in this way hoping to meet a few problems.

Comment: @NeilBartlett my second response did not want to be offensive. Peace :)

Comment: @NeilBartlett plus i've also used your "OGSi in practice" in addiction at "OSGi in action" for start to study OSGi. Great work.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to run it all in OSGi? Like this:

```
@Component(provide = Servlet.class, properties = { "alias=/someUrl" })
public class MyServer extends HttpServlet {
 BundleContext bundleContext;


 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws  ServletException, IOException {

     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     out.println("OSGi On the Job and do your stuff from here");
 }
 // Your Activator
 @Activate
 public void activate(final BundleContext aContext, Map<String, Object> props) {
  this.bundleContext = aContext;

 }



}
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question? Applet is run on end user browser.

Comment: Sorry if I'm off base, I only thought about the problem briefly. I gravitate towards OSGi solutions (questions too). :-)  It's an interesting topic as well.